# Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a graph given by $x=by^a$ where $b\in \mathbb{R}$ is just a constant and $a \in \mathbb{Q}_+^*$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, tangent-line, smooth-functions

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a graph given by $$x=by^a$$ where $b\in \mathbb{R}$ is just a constant and $a \in \mathbb{Q}_+^*$.

Under the assumptions above, Is it possible to say that the graph $\mathcal{C}$ is smooth and tangent to the $y-$axis to order $[a]$ (where $[a]$ is greatest integer less than or equal to $a$)?

Comment: Now $x^n=b^n y^m,$ where $a=\frac{m}{n},$ $(m,n)=1.$ If $m>n$ the tangent cone from algebraic geometry is $x^n,$ that is the $y$-axis is $n$-fold tangent. Examples include $x=y^2,$ $x=y^3,\ldots$ where the $y$-axis is simply tangent, and the usual cusp $x^2=y^3,$ where it is doubly tangent. There are also higher cusps, and $x^3=y^5,$ that is triply tangent but over the reals it looks smooth, but the derivative of $x^\frac35$ blows up at the origin. If $m=n,$ $x=by$ are the only curves. If $m<n$ the $x$-axis is tangent at the origin. So you'd need $a< 1$ for the tangency, $n=1$ for $C^\infty$.